# My UV unwrapped image flips between edit mode and preview mode

Tags: uv

this is a weird one. I have an unwrapped cylinder. I have checked the uv map is correctly oriented. I added the texture coordinates and a mapping node.

When I look at it in edit mode, the image shows correctly.
[image: edit mode]

But, when I go to render or look at rendered mode, the image flips 90 degrees to a horizontal position.

[image: Rendered preview in cycles and node tree]
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi @Jacym Michal. I think you may have made a suggestion earlier about modifiers, but I don't see it here now. You were right! It was a boolean issue. I had a couple of boolean modifiers in the stack. As soon as I turned them off, the uv righted itself. When I applied the booleans and looked at the uv, it had changed pretty drastically. So, new order of ops for me: apply booleans and then mess with materials! Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Glad you made it work :). I removed the comment as I was sure you already tried it.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't! I was too tired and never even considered the modifiers. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out with a suggestion from [Jachym Michal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/78972/jachym-michal) (I think it was you).

The boolean modifiers were messing with the uv map. Which makes sense, when I think about it.

After applying the modifiers, I needed to go back in and redo the UV map to make the image appear where I wanted.